# delphi wsaasyncselecy not working in windows services application

Tags: delphi, service, winsock2, wsaasyncselect

I write service application with Winsock. I want have asynchronous sockets. In TThread in Execute I have example code:

```
procedure TNasluchujPolaczenia.Execute;
var
  WindowsSockets: WSAData;
begin
  WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), WindowsSockets);
  mysocket:= Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  sizesettings := SizeOf(SettingsSocket)
  bind(mysocket, SettingsSocket, SizeOf(SettingsSocket));
  listen(mysocket, 10);
  while myend <> True do
  begin
    WSAAsyncSelect(mysocket, Handle, WM_USER, FD_READ or FD_ACCEPT);
    accept(mysocket, pointer(@SettingsSocket), @sizesettings);
  ...
  end;           
  Shutdown(mysocket, SD_BOTH);
  CloseSocket(mysocket);
  WSACleanUp();
  Terminate;
end;
```

this not working:

```
WSAAsyncSelect(mysocket, Handle, WM_USER, FD_READ or FD_ACCEPT);
```

and I don't know why. My service is blocked on this **acccept()**, when I have connection, my loop once execute and next blocked. I checked my code in plain application everything is ok.

Comment: You're missing error handling in your code. Use `WSAGetLastError` for every function that it supports.

Comment: I have error handling, this code is a example. WSAGetLastError for WSAAsyncSelect() return error 10022.

Comment: I think, that problem is handle to service. I use handle to my TThread and seem to be ok.

Comment: That error is [`WSAEINVAL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAEINVAL), invalid argument. And you're on the right track, `TThread.Handle` is not a `HWND` window handle. It is the handle returned by the `CreateThread` function. Pity that Delphi is not more strong typed because you could get a compiler error for this.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with window handle. It is solutions: `AllocateHWnd(MyMessageProc)`